# When I write a file in mode "wb", what will happens?

Tags: c++, c

When I write "asklfj123" into a file in mode "wb", then I open it in vim,
why I can still see  asklfj ?but I can not see 123 in vim. I mean that when I write it in mode "wb", the program will not convert it into ASCII code, but the editor will open it with ASCII code, then it should be garbage values in text editor, isn't it? then why I can still see them?

Comment: Please show the code you're using. There's no way to explain what's going on without seeing what you're actually doing. (Also one of the two tags is probably superfluous. Please only tag with the language you're actually using.)

Comment: Meta-proposal: adding the `c` and `c++` tags at the same time should not be possible.

Comment: @zeta: That is just not how it works.

Comment: @Zeta Wrong, wrong, wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary mode means "don't translate anything".

In "text" mode (that is "not binary mode"), on some systems, the representation of for example newlines is different between the OS's file representation and the standard `'\n'` that C uses for newline representation.

In some systems there are also special characters to represent end of file. When in text mode, these characters are translated and understood to mean newline and end of file, respectively.

Now, writing text in "binary" mode will work just fine, and I would suspect your problem is something else - without code, it's impossible to answer what. The mention of `vim` also makes me think that you are using Linux or some other Unix-based system, where newline is indeed the same as `'\n'`, so no translation is done in these systems.

Edit:

Given the code, it's typical "undefined behaviour", because:

```
char test[30] = "adadsf123";
...
fwrite(test, sizeof(double), 6, fp);
```

The arguments for [`fwrite`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/fread.3.html) is the data to be written, the size of each member, and the number of items, and finally the file object to write it to.

In this case, a string of 30 bytes is given as input, then sizeof(double) as the size of each item, and 6 items. Since `sizeof(double)` is more than 30, some random garbage is being output. What that random garbage is, is depending on what is stored i the memory after the `test` variable. In the code posted, that appears to be the `fp` variable. It's hard to say exactly what the `fp`'s value will be. But `fwrite` is doing exactly what it has been told, writing binary data to a binary file. ASCII characters, in "binary" will still appear the same, the binary code of 'A' is 01000001, and that will appear, if interpreted as ASCII shows as 'A' - and VIM and `putc` will interpret that as ASCII.

Comment: you mean that other character will still be written in ASCII code,even if in binary mode? or every character will be written in ASCII code ,and program do nothing ,just written them?

Comment: I wonder why I write them in mode binary, Why they are not garbled character? Can text editor know binary? I mean I think editor can only know ASCII code, isn't it ?

Comment: @XianB - the value of whatever you write is what gets written, both in binary and in text mode. In some contexts that value is treated as a character on the display, but it's still a numeric value.

Comment: well,I got it, well, Why a number was written in mode binary,then it will be unrecognizable characters when I the file with vim?

Comment: It depends on the number. But in your original question you asserted you are writing the exact *string* "asklfj123", and that should have worked. You need to show your code.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 FILE  * fp;
 char  ch;
 char test[30] = "adadsf123";
 fp = fopen("file1","wb");
 fwrite(test, sizeof(double), 6, fp);


 fclose(fp);

 fp = fopen("file1", "r");

 while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
  putc(ch ,stdout);

 return 0;
}

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to paste here ,the out put is adadsf123######################`1#�Ͻ########8=

Comment: Please edit your post -- it will make your code readable. Any particular reason you are treating a char string as a double in `fwrite`?

Comment: I' sorry, I just don't know how to express my idea, I think I have waste so much your time,I am sorry. well ,just let me think it over my self. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Found it yet? *This* is the exact line that causes unexpected characters to appear in your output: `fwrite(test, sizeof(double), 6, fp);` -- and I gave a hint to the solution above.

Comment: @Mats Petersson - You mean that in "binary"  every things will not be translated , characters are characters (ASCII), digits are digits, they are written into files just like they are stored in memory(characters are stored in memory as ASCII too?), but in "text" C will translate them into readable format, I mean they all are translated into character(Since characters are characters, so they might will not be translated),right? However ,since characters always be written as ASCII(in text and binary). So even if they are written in "binary", we can still see them in vim,instead of garbage?

Comment: Both are stored in binary form in the file, but in "text" mode, certain special characters, such as newline needs translating ON SOME archtitectures, for example on Windows, from a single character newline (also known as linefeed) becomes two characters, Carriage Return and Linefeed (and CR+LF is translated to a single newline when reading). When reading a text file, on Windows, a CTRL-Z will turn into "end-of-file". When writing binary, newline is just a single character on all OS's, and CTRL-Z is just another byte of input. Yes, ASCII will be visible in VIM whatever mode you are writing it.